# How to Add "custom Class name" to bing Map Infobox

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing

I am creating infoboxes on map, and want to change/add Default class name.
this way i am creating Infoboxes.

```
infoboxOptions = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(Point,{
                   class:'new-class-name'
                   title: 'Title',
                   description: Address,
                   visible: true,
                   offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 15),
                   showCloseButton: false,
               });
```

so can anyone help to add "class:'new-class-name'" class name to infobox

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to create custom HTML that includes your class name and pass it into the htmlContent property of the infobox. You can find an example on how to create a custom infobox using HTML here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750271.aspx